# Read Complex Xml file in java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I am able to read many type of xml file in java. but today i got a xml file and not able to read its details.

```
<ENVELOPE>
    <BILLFIXED>
        <BILLDATE>1-Jul-2017</BILLDATE>
        <BILLREF>1</BILLREF>
        <BILLPARTY>Party1</BILLPARTY>
    </BILLFIXED>
    <BILLCL>-10800.00</BILLCL>
    <BILLPDC/>
    <BILLFINAL>-10800.00</BILLFINAL>
    <BILLDUE>1-Jul-2017</BILLDUE>
    <BILLOVERDUE>30</BILLOVERDUE>
    <BILLFIXED>
        <BILLDATE>1-Jul-2017</BILLDATE>
        <BILLREF>2</BILLREF>
        <BILLPARTY>Party2</BILLPARTY>
    </BILLFIXED>
    <BILLCL>-2000.00</BILLCL>
    <BILLPDC/>
    <BILLFINAL>-2000.00</BILLFINAL>
    <BILLDUE>1-Jul-2017</BILLDUE>
    <BILLOVERDUE>30</BILLOVERDUE>
    <BILLFIXED>
        <BILLDATE>1-Jul-2017</BILLDATE>
        <BILLREF>3</BILLREF>
        <BILLPARTY>Party3</BILLPARTY>
    </BILLFIXED>
    <BILLCL>-1416.00</BILLCL>
    <BILLPDC/>
    <BILLFINAL>-1416.00</BILLFINAL>
    <BILLDUE>31-Jul-2017</BILLDUE>
    <BILLOVERDUE>0</BILLOVERDUE>
</ENVELOPE>
```

I am using this code for read xml file. I am able to read data inside `<BILLFIXED>` tag but not able to read data outside of this like <`BILLFINAL>` and `<BILLDUE>` etc.

```
try {
          File fXmlFile = new File("filepath");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
            
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            NodeList billNodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("ENVELOPE");
            for(int i=0;i<billNodeList.getLength();i++){
                Node voucherNode = billNodeList.item(i);
                Element voucherElement = (Element) voucherNode;
                NodeList nList = voucherElement.getElementsByTagName("BILLFIXED");
                
                for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
                    Node insideNode = nList.item(temp);
                    Element voucherElements = (Element) insideNode;
                    System.out.println(voucherElements.getElementsByTagName("BILLDATE").item(0).getTextContent());
                    System.out.println(voucherElements.getElementsByTagName("BILLREF").item(0).getTextContent());
                    System.out.println(voucherElements.getElementsByTagName("BILLPARTY").item(0).getTextContent());
                    System.out.println(voucherElements.getElementsByTagName("BILLFINAL").item(0).getTextContent());
                    System.out.println(voucherElements.getElementsByTagName("BILLOVERDUE").item(0).getTextContent());
                }
            }
            
            
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am try all possible way which i know that but currently i am not able to find any solution.
If anyone have any solution please share with me.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it, is to "fix" the XML to be more well-structured, e.g. like this:

```java
// Fix the XML
Element envelopeElem = doc.getDocumentElement();
List<Node> children = new ArrayList<>();
for (Node child = envelopeElem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling())
    children.add(child);
Element billElem = null;
for (Node child : children) {
    if (child.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE && "BILLFIXED".equals(child.getNodeName()))
        envelopeElem.insertBefore(billElem = doc.createElement("BILL"), child);
    if (billElem != null)
        billElem.appendChild(child);
}
```

The code basically creates a new `<BILL>` element as a child of `<ENVELOPE>` whenever it encounters a `<BILLFIXED>` element, then moves all subsequent nodes into the `<BILL>` element.

The result is that the XML in the DOM tree looks like this<sup>1</sup>, which should be easier for you to process:

```xml
<ENVELOPE>
    <BILL>
        <BILLFIXED>
            <BILLDATE>1-Jul-2017</BILLDATE>
            <BILLREF>1</BILLREF>
            <BILLPARTY>Party1</BILLPARTY>
        </BILLFIXED>
        <BILLCL>-10800.00</BILLCL>
        <BILLPDC/>
        <BILLFINAL>-10800.00</BILLFINAL>
        <BILLDUE>1-Jul-2017</BILLDUE>
        <BILLOVERDUE>30</BILLOVERDUE>
    </BILL>
    <BILL>
        <BILLFIXED>
            <BILLDATE>1-Jul-2017</BILLDATE>
            <BILLREF>2</BILLREF>
            <BILLPARTY>Party2</BILLPARTY>
        </BILLFIXED>
        <BILLCL>-2000.00</BILLCL>
        <BILLPDC/>
        <BILLFINAL>-2000.00</BILLFINAL>
        <BILLDUE>1-Jul-2017</BILLDUE>
        <BILLOVERDUE>30</BILLOVERDUE>
    </BILL>
    <BILL>
        <BILLFIXED>
            <BILLDATE>1-Jul-2017</BILLDATE>
            <BILLREF>3</BILLREF>
            <BILLPARTY>Party3</BILLPARTY>
        </BILLFIXED>
        <BILLCL>-1416.00</BILLCL>
        <BILLPDC/>
        <BILLFINAL>-1416.00</BILLFINAL>
        <BILLDUE>31-Jul-2017</BILLDUE>
        <BILLOVERDUE>0</BILLOVERDUE>
    </BILL>
</ENVELOPE>
```

<sup>1) The XML has been reformatted for human readability, i.e. it has been re-indented.</sup>

Comment: File size is too large i.e we may have 10000+ data in xml file. Is this way is convenient for large xml file.

Comment: For large files consider using the Streams API and a SAX parser instead of a DOM parser to avoid reading it all into memory

Comment: @MostchRomi How can file be too large for this solution, which is based on the same choice of XML parser using *in the question*, i.e. the DOM parser? If you needed a non-DOM solution, why on earth did you show DOM code in the question, without any mention of size issues? This answer fits the question. If you have a different question, I suggest you *create* a new one.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't well-structured XML. Inside your `<envelope>` tags there is nothing to indicate the start of each set of six attributes that constitute a 'bill'. You'd normally expect that each one would have a `<bill>` and `</bill>` tag to contain them. And this is going to confuse the parser...

Comment: I am getting this xml from tally server. so we can not say its not well structured.

Comment: Just because you are getting it from an existing server doesn't mean it's correct. There is bad code everywhere in the world! Instead of returning an array of bill objects, they are returning a flat-file of records with a few XML tags injected into it. I would adopt @krishna's approach of adding some `<bill></bill>` tags to act as record separators, then processing the file.

Answer (score 0):

As per sample XML, it has data for 3 records. But each record does not have any separation. Looks like each field data populated into XML tag and written into file.

There 2 possible option I would suggest

1. JAVA based : As Andreas suggested, Read the file content and add a root tag for each record which would give finite XML structure then would be easier to handle. Performance impact may raise when the input file is in large size.
2. Transformation based : Try STX transformation which would convert the structure to required format either XML or even flat file. Then processing would be simpler